# How to scale background image proportionally which is in css background of a div?

Tags: jquery, css

How to scale background image proportionally which is in background of a div? [I'm not asking background resizing of full `<body>`background.](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/)

In this jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/aQCen/1/  you will see that text is re-sizing proportionally when you reszie the browser or js fiddle result window. but in this image is not resizing. and I also want to scale the image like text.

I already know the way to resize the image if use it as `<img>` in mark-up. but in this question I'm asking about [how to resize the image which is in css background](http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/aQCen/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;
background-color:red;
background-image:url('test.jpg');
background-size:contain; 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;"></div>

<div style="height:100px;width:100px;
background-color:red;
background-image:url('test.jpg');
background-size:cover; 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;"></div>
```

working in gecko/webkit/opera and probably newers msie

full documentation at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aQCen/2/ here it is, the background-color is placed only to show you the real size of the box

Comment: but size of image is too short in this and not in proportion

Comment: but i want box size as same size of background image

Comment: you can't, because you want that the size of the box depends by its background image, you should use <img> instead! don't keep searching for a solution, because I'm totally sure that you can't do this with background-images, even with css3 :)

Comment: no i don't want to make the size box dependent on background image. but I want to resize the background image proportionally. see here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/fZ4v3/1/

Comment: same thing, you can't proportionally re-size a background of a fixed size box, the box should be made with relative units

Comment: OK now I'm using relative units http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/fZ4v3/4/ and even if there is any jquery way to do this i have no problem

Answer (score 5):

You can use the css3 property "**background-size**" however only IE9+, Firefox 4 and Webkit browsers support this. The "**cover**" and "**contain**" values might be worth looking at - cover scales the background image to the maximum width or height of the container without cropping the image, whereas contain scales to completely fill the container while some areas may not be visible.

See more here: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: plus 1 to the cover value